# Limit Directives to Certain Controllers or Modules

Tags: angularjs

I have a module `A` which requires module `B`. Module `B` may require module `C` and module `D`. The modules `B`, `C` and `D` define directives. I don't want these directives be accessible in the scope of module `A`, i.e., if there is an HTML tag like one of the directives in modules `B`, `C`, `D`, I don't want it to get processed.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1:**
I am writing a framework for an application which many teams will have their own "pages" in it and these teams may have their own Angular modules. I want what I asked for in order to isolate their pages so when one defines a directive the other team's pages do not get affected.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this? What is the scenario?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Everything in all modules is combined into the main module which is then "the app". Show some code where there is a problem

Comment: This is not supported by Angular, so name collisions will overwrite previously defined services/directives/controllers

Comment: I am writing a framework for an application which many teams will have their own "pages" in it and these teams may have their own Angular modules. I want what I asked for in order to isolate their pages so when one defines a directive the other team's pages do not get affected.

Comment: this isn't one of the design goals for Angular Directives.  Directives are not "modules"; "At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element ...".  While you could perhaps attach custom behavior that enables or disables a directive or features, you can't really makes directives aware of other elements on the page.  This really feels like an XY question in it's current form.